# Does it make an essential difference for SR or GR if the speed of light had a different but finite value?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, speed-of-light, physical-constants

It's commonly known among physicists that the speed of light has a constant value in SR. Except in GR, but I'm not so sure. I THINK, intuitively, it doesn't. I guess I could have done some research on this topic about which various questions are asked, but I didn't make the effort to do so because I don't think it's of real importance to my question.

If the speed of light had a different value as it actually has, would that make an **essential** difference for Special or General Relativity?

Comment: I've removed a comment that should have been posted as an answer.

Comment: @Ben Crowel I think my question hasn't got anything to do with the origin of the speed of light. That (the origin of its value) is not what I ask. Isn't it? So why it's a duplicate?

Comment: @rob Did you remove the comment because of its content or because, as you say, it should be an answer? I think it's sad because I haven't read it before you removed it. And I can't see who made the comment, so I'm not capable to contact the person who made the comment. Is there something to do about it? I'm very curious!

Comment: One reason (of several) not to post answers as comments is that it's not possible to downvote the ones that aren't useful. It was a two-word answer.